# Getting "413 Request Entity Too Large" when talking to WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service, `Server`, which accepts requests from a console application `Client`. When sending the data (which is relatively large), I get the following exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large.
```

I thought I had the limits correctly set in the config files, but apparently I'm mistaken?

Here's the relevant part of `Server`'s `app.config`:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>

<services>
  <service name="Services.Server">
    <endpoint bindingConfiguration="LargeWeb" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Interfaces.IServer" />
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="LargeWeb" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

</system.serviceModel>
```

And here's `Client`'s `app.config`:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>

<client>
  <endpoint name="serverEndpoint" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeWeb" contract="Interfaces.IServer" />
</client>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="LargeWeb" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

</system.serviceModel>
```

And finally, this is how `Client` calls the `Server`'s method:

```cs
using (var cf = new WebChannelFactory<IServer>("serverEndpoint", serverAddress))
{
    var channel = cf.CreateChannel();
    channel.SomeMethod(some, arguments);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You need to have maxReceivedMessageSize size to correct size. As you mentioned, you have the setting in your config. can you check what is the size of response in kb you are expecting using Fiddler ?

Comment: @Agalo, I cannot check so now, but the sizes are certainly up to ~ten megabytes, i.e. relatively large, but nothing truly extreme. Simply setting `maxReceivedMessageSize` within the config files is not enough? Thanks!

Comment: 2147483647 is the number of bytes, which equals ~2 GB.  For anything larger, look into [streaming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx) or [chunking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Tim, my messages are nowhere near 2GB in size. The limits set in the config files should be enough, but it appears they are not being applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that `Client` was residing in a UnitTest project, and the issue arised while running a unit test. When running a unit test, only the UnitTest project's config file is taken into account, so the `<service>` parts of the `Server` config need to be copied into it.

This way, only one config file is ever used: both `Server` and `Client` read it for their configuration.

After that, things work fine.